# Как выделить строку if в функции int* delete_FiveNumber и size_t get_FiveNumber_count в отдельную функцию с использованием stringstream?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/**
 * \brief Перечислимый тип способов задания массива.
 */
enum class FillMethod
{
    /**
     * \brief ввод вручную.
     */
    KEYBOARD,

    /**
     * \brief создание с использованием генератора случайных чисел.
     */
     RANDOM
};

/**
 * \brief Метод заполнения массива
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \param FillMethod Способ создания массива
 * \param MIN Нижняя граница для случайных чисел
 * \param MAX Верхняя граница для случайных чисел
 * \return Заполненный массив
 */
int* get_array(const size_t size, const int FillMethod, const int MIN, const int MAX);

/**
 * \brief Функция для получения размера массива
 * \param message Мотивационное сообщение для пользователя
 * \return Размер массива
 */
size_t get_size(const std::string& message);

/**
 * \brief Вывод в строку элементов массива
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \return Строка с элементами
 */
string to_string(const int*, const size_t size);

/**
 * \brief Заменяет минимальный элемент массива на средний, с нечетным количеством
 * \param size Размер массива
 */
void replace_minimal_elem(int*, const size_t size);

/**
 * \brief Возвращает массив, в котором удалены все числа, в которых есть цифра 5
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \param newsize Размер нового массива
 * \return Массив, в котором удалены все числа, в которых есть цифра 5
 */
int* delete_FiveNumber(int*, size_t size, size_t newsize);

/**
 * \brief Считает количество чисел с цифрой 5 (\a index)
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \return Количество чисел с цифрой 5
 */
size_t get_FiveNumber_count(int*, size_t size);

/**
 * \brief Создает из исходного массива новый массив С по определенному правилу
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \return массив С
 */
int* сreate_a(int*, const size_t size);


/**
 * \brief Точка входа в программу
 * \return 0 в случае успеха
 */
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    auto error_code = 0;
    int* my_array = nullptr;
    const int MIN = -1000;
    const int MAX = 1000;
    try
    {
        auto size = get_size("Введите размер массива = ");
        cout << "Выберите способ создания массива: " << static_cast<int>(FillMethod::KEYBOARD) << " - вручную, " << static_cast<int>(FillMethod::RANDOM) << " - заполнить случайными числами ";
        int FillMethod;
        cin >> FillMethod;
        my_array = get_array(size, FillMethod, MIN, MAX);
        cout << "Полученный массив:\n";
        cout << to_string(my_array, size);
        replace_minimal_elem(my_array, size);
        size_t FiveNumber_count = get_FiveNumber_count(my_array, size);
        size_t new_size = size - FiveNumber_count;
        int* new_array = delete_FiveNumber(my_array, size, new_size);
        cout << "\nМассив после удаления всех элементов в записи которых есть цифра 5:\n";
        cout << to_string(new_array, new_size);
        int* massive_a = сreate_a(my_array, size);
        cout << "\nМассив A:\n";
        cout << to_string(massive_a, size);
        if (new_array != nullptr) {
            delete[] new_array;
            new_array = nullptr;
        }
        if (massive_a != nullptr) {
            delete massive_a;
            massive_a = nullptr;
        }
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what();
        error_code = 1;
    }

    if (my_array != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] my_array;
        my_array = nullptr;
    }
    return error_code;
}

size_t get_size(const std::string& message)
{
    int size = -1;
    std::cout << message;
    std::cin >> size;

    if (size <= 0)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Неправильный размер. Значение должно быть больше или равно нулю.");
    }

    return size;
}

int* get_array(const size_t size, const int FillMethod, const int MIN, const int MAX)
{

    const auto array = new int[size];
    //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::random_device rd;

    //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    const std::uniform_int_distribution<> uniform_int_distribution(MIN, MAX);
    for (size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        switch (FillMethod)
        {
        case static_cast<int>(FillMethod::KEYBOARD):
        {
            cout << "Введите " << index + 1 << " элемент массива = ";
            cin >> array[index];
            break;
        }
        case static_cast<int>(FillMethod::RANDOM):
        {
            array[index] = uniform_int_distribution(gen);
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "Ошибка!";
        }
    }

    return array;
}

string to_string(const int* array, const size_t size)
{
    if (array == nullptr)
        throw invalid_argument("Массив не существует");

    stringstream buffer;
    if (size == 0) {
        buffer << "{}";
    }
    else {
        buffer << "{";
        for (size_t index = 0; index < size - 1; index++)
        {
            buffer << array[index] << ", ";
        }
        buffer << array[size - 1] << "}";
    }
    return buffer.str();
}

void replace_minimal_elem(int* array, const size_t size) {
    int min = array[0], MinIndex = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
            MinIndex = i;
        }
    }
    array[MinIndex] = array[size / 2];
    cout << "\nМассив после замены минимального элемента на средний:\n";
    cout << to_string(array, size);

}

int* delete_FiveNumber(int* array, size_t size, size_t new_size) {
    int* new_array = new int[new_size];
    size_t index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int temp = abs(array[i]);
        if (!(temp % 10 == 5 or (temp / 10) % 10 == 5 or (temp / 100) % 10 == 5 or temp / 1000 == 5)) {
            new_array[i - index] = array[i];
        }
        else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return new_array;
}

size_t get_FiveNumber_count(int* array, size_t size) {
    size_t FiveNumber_counter = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int temp = abs(array[i]);
        if (temp % 10 == 5 or (temp / 10) % 10 == 5 or (temp / 100) % 10 == 5 or temp / 1000 == 5) {
            FiveNumber_counter++;
        }
    }
    return FiveNumber_counter;
}

int* сreate_a(int* С, const size_t size) {
    int* massive_a = new int[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (С[i] % 2 == 0) {
            massive_a[i] = pow(С[i], 2);
        }
        else {
            massive_a[i] = С[i] * 2;
        }
    }
    return massive_a;
}
```

Comment: Вообще на GCC 11.0 этот код валится из-за того, что местами Вы написали русскую "С" вместо латинской "C", ну и ещё `uniform_int_distribution(MIN, MAX);` лучше не делать константным — из-за этого компилятор тоже ругается

Comment: Благодарю, но что же всё таки мне делать с костыльной строкой if (!(temp % 10 == 5 or (temp / 10) % 10 == 5 or (temp / 100) % 10 == 5 or temp / 1000 == 5))? Может создать функцию или цикл? Распишите пожалуйста. Ведь будь интервал не 1000, а миллион, то было бы совсем плохо

Comment: Или как-то записать функцию, которая проверяет, есть ли в числе цифра пять

Comment: Можно вообще преобразовать `temp` в строку, а затем подсчитать её при помощи встроенного метода C++. Я подробно расписал об этом в своё ответе, проверяйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я уже указал на замечания, не относящиеся к самой задаче (вроде 'С' на кириллице и 'C' на латинице + неконстантного `uniform_int_distribution`), теперь перехожу к самому вопросу.

Вообще можно всё выражение в `if` (а оно выглядит так: `temp % 10 == 5 or (temp / 10) % 10 == 5 or (temp / 100) % 10 == 5 or temp / 1000 == 5`) сократить примерно в два раза: для этого мы сначала переводим элемент массива в строковый вид с помощью [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), а затем подсчитываем число символов `'5'` в строке через функцию [`count(temp.begin(), temp.end(), '5')`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) (алгоритм итерационный, поэтому через `.begin()` и `.end()`). Кстати, чтобы этот метод заработал, нужно дополнительно подключить `#include <algorithm>`.

Таким образом можно преобразовать все эти выражения к уже существующим функциям, не создавая при этом новых функций, и окончательный код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/**
 * \brief Перечислимый тип способов задания массива.
 */
enum class FillMethod
{
    /**
     * \brief ввод вручную.
     */
    KEYBOARD,

    /**
     * \brief создание с использованием генератора случайных чисел.
     */
     RANDOM
};

/**
 * \brief Метод заполнения массива
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \param FillMethod Способ создания массива
 * \param MIN Нижняя граница для случайных чисел
 * \param MAX Верхняя граница для случайных чисел
 * \return Заполненный массив
 */
int* get_array(const size_t size, const int FillMethod, const int MIN, const int MAX);

/**
 * \brief Функция для получения размера массива
 * \param message Мотивационное сообщение для пользователя
 * \return Размер массива
 */
size_t get_size(const std::string& message);

/**
 * \brief Вывод в строку элементов массива
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \return Строка с элементами
 */
string to_string(const int*, const size_t size);

/**
 * \brief Заменяет минимальный элемент массива на средний, с нечетным количеством
 * \param size Размер массива
 */
void replace_minimal_elem(int*, const size_t size);

/**
 * \brief Возвращает массив, в котором удалены все числа, в которых есть цифра 5
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \param newsize Размер нового массива
 * \return Массив, в котором удалены все числа, в которых есть цифра 5
 */
int* delete_FiveNumber(int*, size_t size, size_t newsize);

/**
 * \brief Считает количество чисел с цифрой 5 (\a index)
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \return Количество чисел с цифрой 5
 */
size_t get_FiveNumber_count(int*, size_t size);

/**
 * \brief Создает из исходного массива новый массив С по определенному правилу
 * \param size Размер массива
 * \return массив С
 */
int* create_a(int*, const size_t size);


/**
 * \brief Точка входа в программу
 * \return 0 в случае успеха
 */
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    auto error_code = 0;
    int* my_array = nullptr;
    const int MIN = -1000;
    const int MAX = 1000;
    try
    {
        auto size = get_size("Введите размер массива = ");
        cout << "Выберите способ создания массива: " << static_cast<int>(FillMethod::KEYBOARD) << " - вручную, " << static_cast<int>(FillMethod::RANDOM) << " - заполнить случайными числами ";
        int FillMethod;
        cin >> FillMethod;
        my_array = get_array(size, FillMethod, MIN, MAX);
        cout << "Полученный массив:\n";
        cout << to_string(my_array, size);
        replace_minimal_elem(my_array, size);
        size_t FiveNumber_count = get_FiveNumber_count(my_array, size);
        size_t new_size = size - FiveNumber_count;
        int* new_array = delete_FiveNumber(my_array, size, new_size);
        cout << "\nМассив после удаления всех элементов в записи которых есть цифра 5:\n";
        cout << to_string(new_array, new_size);
        int* massive_a = create_a(my_array, size);
        cout << "\nМассив A:\n";
        cout << to_string(massive_a, size);
        if (new_array != nullptr) {
            delete[] new_array;
            new_array = nullptr;
        }
        if (massive_a != nullptr) {
            delete massive_a;
            massive_a = nullptr;
        }
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what();
        error_code = 1;
    }

    if (my_array != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] my_array;
        my_array = nullptr;
    }
    return error_code;
}

size_t get_size(const std::string& message)
{
    int size = -1;
    std::cout << message;
    std::cin >> size;

    if (size <= 0)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Неправильный размер. Значение должно быть больше или равно нулю.");
    }

    return size;
}

int* get_array(const size_t size, const int FillMethod, const int MIN, const int MAX)
{

    const auto array = new int[size];
    //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::random_device rd;

    //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> uniform_int_distribution(MIN, MAX);
    for (size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        switch (FillMethod)
        {
        case static_cast<int>(FillMethod::KEYBOARD):
        {
            cout << "Введите " << index + 1 << " элемент массива = ";
            cin >> array[index];
            break;
        }
        case static_cast<int>(FillMethod::RANDOM):
        {
            array[index] = uniform_int_distribution(gen);
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "Ошибка!";
        }
    }

    return array;
}

string to_string(const int* array, const size_t size)
{
    if (array == nullptr)
        throw invalid_argument("Массив не существует");

    stringstream buffer;
    if (size == 0) {
        buffer << "{}";
    }
    else {
        buffer << "{";
        for (size_t index = 0; index < size - 1; index++)
        {
            buffer << array[index] << ", ";
        }
        buffer << array[size - 1] << "}";
    }
    return buffer.str();
}

void replace_minimal_elem(int* array, const size_t size) {
    int min = array[0], MinIndex = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
            MinIndex = i;
        }
    }
    array[MinIndex] = array[size / 2];
    cout << "\nМассив после замены минимального элемента на средний:\n";
    cout << to_string(array, size);

}

int* delete_FiveNumber(int* array, size_t size, size_t new_size) {
    int* new_array = new int[new_size];
    size_t index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        string temp = to_string(abs(array[i]));
        if (count(temp.begin(), temp.end(), '5') == 0) {
            new_array[i - index] = array[i];
        }
        else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return new_array;
}

size_t get_FiveNumber_count(int* array, size_t size) {
    size_t FiveNumber_counter = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        string temp = to_string(abs(array[i]));
        if (count(temp.begin(), temp.end(), '5') > 0) {
            FiveNumber_counter++;
        }
    }
    return FiveNumber_counter;
}

int* create_a(int* C, const size_t size) {
    int* massive_a = new int[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (C[i] % 2 == 0) {
            massive_a[i] = pow(C[i], 2);
        }
        else {
            massive_a[i] = C[i] * 2;
        }
    }
    return massive_a;
}
```

P.S. К слову, эту замену можно считать в некотором роде универсальной: если мы захотим увеличить длину чисел от 4 до 7 или даже 12, не нужно тогда городить условия; преобразователь в строку и `count` сделают всю работу при любых числах/строках. :)